# query string issue mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following python script:

```
import pdb
import sys
import os
import csv
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

def main():
    pass

def getWholeCollection(collection_name):
    for property in collection_name.find("{"zip":33801}"):
        print property


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient()
    data_base = client.hkpr_dbw
    properties_collection = data_base.properties

    getWholeCollection(properties_collection)
```

I keep getting an error around `{"zip":33801}` which works fine in the mongo shell.  I tried """{"zip":33801}""".

I'd like to make the query a variable at some point.  How do I use these strings?

Comment: Try `for property in collection_name.find({"zip":33801}):`

Comment: that's it.  no need for quotes. Thanks!  want to put that as the answer?

Comment: No worries :-) I think @DanielRoseman answer below suffices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put it in a string. The MongoDB driver will convert the Python dict into the relevant format.

```
collection_name.find({"zip": 33801})
```